# Is this a Tick or a spider?

Tags: bugs, dogs, ticks, spider

I live in Lubbock, Texas and have never seen a tick in my life. I just moved to a town house that is more outside of town, so there are several cotton fields close by. I have a small dog who is on flea and tick guard, but we haven't been anywhere recently. I found it on my bed which my dog gets on too. It was moving really fast like a spider, but I can't tell after researching and looking at pictures. Is it a tick? And if so what do I do since it was in my house on my bed?? I am PANICKING[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is a tick. Spiders have two distinct body parts (thorax and abdomen) as well as a fifth pair of appendages called pedipalps near the head. On a spider you might also notice spinnerets at the rear end.

@bob1 offers a better breakdown here: [Is this tick or spider?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22608/is-this-tick-or-spider)